# connection string issue with SQL EXPRESS 2008

Tags: c#, string, sql-server-2008, connection

I have a connection string in c# that cant connect to my instance running on studio express 2008. Both the application and the database are on the same machine. I have mixed mode on, and my instance name (found in my registry) is SqlExpress. I can log into the database with my user name and password but not in my connection string.

```
SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;" + "Initial Catalog=test;"
+ "Integrated Security=false;" + "User Id=test;" 
+ "Password=test;" + "connection timeout=300;" + "pooling=false;");
```

Comment: What sort of application are you trying to connect from? Is this a web application?

Comment: what error message you are getting?

Comment: dude we use double slash for file directory not connection string

Comment: its a c# application. i need  two slashes unless i use @. Either way still wont connect. I am out of ideas. It worked fine on the 2005 version. I dont know what other features I need to enable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SqlConnection cn = new 
    SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=test;"
    +"Connection Timeout=300;User ID=test;Password=test;Pooling=false")
```

Comment: Its in C# so I need both slashes. It wont compile without it.

Comment: Oops, forgot the most important part.  The @ should allow it to compile.  I've edited my answer again to include.

Comment: See here for more details:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Also note that I changed to server and database in the string.

Comment: Great advice..but it still says it cant connect. Anything else I need to enable in Configuration tools???

Comment: I have my program throw an error and it says cant find or connect to database still...

Comment: Can you see/add the database in the visual studio server explorer (under the view menu)?  If so you can right click on the server and get the same connection string that visual studio is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"))
{
}
```